# optimizing the 3 queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am just trying to figure out on how to optimize the below sequence of queries into a single query.

To be specific, below queries are just like alerts to be displayed to user when he logins into his account.

```
$sq = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totm FROM login as l 
       JOIN msgs m on m.id = l.id 
       WHERE m.tstamp > l.mtstamp AND l.id = $id;";

$sq .= "SELECT COUNT(*) as totp FROM info as u 
        JOIN pst as p on p.cid =  u.cid
        JOIN login as l on l.id = u.id 
        WHERE p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.id <> u.id 
        AND p.type = 0 AND u.id = $id;";

$sq .= "SELECT COUNT(*) as totq FROM info as u 
        JOIN pst as p on p.cid =  u.cid
        JOIN login as l on l.id = u.id 
        WHERE p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.id <> u.id 
        AND p.type = 1 AND u.id = $id";
```

Right now Iam using `mysqli_multi_query()`  to run this multiple queries. 
However I have managed to cut it down into a single query

```
$sq = "SELECT m.totm,p.totp FROM login as l 
       JOIN info as u on u.id = l.id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT tstamp,id,COUNT(*) as 'totm' FROM msgs GROUP BY id) m 
       ON m.id = l.id AND m.tstamp > l.mtstamp
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT tstamp,cid,type,id,COUNT(*) as 'totp' FROM pst 
                  GROUP BY id) p 
       ON p.cid = u.cid AND p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.type = 0 
       AND p.id <> l.id WHERE l.id = $id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT tstamp,cid,type,id,COUNT(*) as 'totp' FROM pst 
                  GROUP BY id) p 
       ON p.cid = u.cid AND p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.type = 1 
       AND p.id <> l.id WHERE l.id = $id LIMIT 1";
```

When I have tried the single query with `EXPLAIN STATEMENT` the query ouput is too bad, many rows are affected.

When I have performed the same on three queries individually, the result was good. I am not sure should I run multiple queries or try single query.

After googling I have found that groupBY causes severe overhead in joins and for many rows. kindly anyone let me know what would be the better way to approach this. Can anyone me help me for writing a more optimized query. Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: union all does work for below 2 queries not with the first one @Fabricator

Comment: are you trying to retrieve the counts for every id or just a specific one?

Comment: specific one I have used $id variable in the sql statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to retrieve the count for a specific id, then I recommend combining your queries as subqueries in the select. There's no sense in using `GROUP BY` since you're looking for the count of a specific id.

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login as l 
       JOIN msgs m on m.id = l.id 
       WHERE m.tstamp > l.mtstamp AND l.id = $id) totm,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info as u 
        JOIN pst as p on p.cid =  u.cid
        JOIN login as l on l.id = u.id 
        WHERE p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.id <> u.id 
        AND p.type = 0 AND u.id = $id) totp,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info as u 
        JOIN pst as p on p.cid =  u.cid
        JOIN login as l on l.id = u.id 
        WHERE p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.id <> u.id 
        AND p.type = 1 AND u.id = $id) totq
```

Contrast this to retrieving counts for every id in which case a `GROUP BY` on `id` would be useful:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.totm,t2.totp,t3.totq
FROM
(SELECT l.id, COUNT(*) as totm FROM login as l 
       JOIN msgs m on m.id = l.id 
       WHERE m.tstamp > l.mtstamp
       GROUP BY l.id) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) as totp FROM info as u 
        JOIN pst as p on p.cid =  u.cid
        JOIN login as l on l.id = u.id 
        WHERE p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.id <> u.id 
        AND p.type = 0 
        GROUP BY u.id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) as totq FROM info as u 
        JOIN pst as p on p.cid =  u.cid
        JOIN login as l on l.id = u.id 
        WHERE p.tstamp > l.ptstamp AND p.id <> u.id 
        AND p.type = 1
        GROUP BY u.id) t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
```

Comment: I did not even know SELECT can be used this way let me try it.